# ImportError: No module named gazebo_msgs.msg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Having installed and using the gazebo simulator environment for a while now I was wondering why when I try to import from a related package I get an error.
...
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose,Twist #works fine
from gazebo_msgs.msg import ModelState
...

ImportError: No module named gazebo_msgs.msg
Looking through folders there doesn’t seem to be a difference between geometry_msgs and gazebo_msgs files/structure.

I want to then subscribe to the listed topic

rostopic list:
...
/gazebo/model_states
...
Then:
self.subModelState = rospy.Subscriber("/gazebo/model_states",ModelState,self.DroneState)

Cheers,
EMP

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203001/importerror:-no-module-named-gazebo_msgs.msg/) by [EMP](https://answers.ros.org/users/21624/emp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which ROS distro are you using?

On **Hydro** and later, this works for me:

```
import rospy
from gazebo_msgs.msg import ModelState
```

---

On **Fuerte**, you need to import `roslib`, like this:

```
import rospy
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('my_pkg')
from gazebo_msgs.msg import ModelState
```

And before you do that, you have to make sure that in `my_pkg/manifest.xml`, you have the line:

```
<depend package="gazebo_msgs"/>
```

---

Of course, in any distro you also need to have `gazebo_msgs` installed and on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`; you can check by running `roscd gazebo_msgs`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EMP](https://answers.ros.org/users/21624/emp/) on 2015-02-14**:
Thanks,
I forgot about the package dependencies:
I added  and it worked obviously.
Thanks again